# Combine iOS and MacOS projects

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a project for iOS, and another project for MacOS.
Now I want to combine them (I want to be able to see them both at once, to be able to share code, and to choose which one to build at the scheme).

I know I can go to one of the projects and create there a new target, but isn't is possible to copy a target from one project to another? 
It would be a lot simpler, and may save some errors that might occur when creating a new target..

Edit: and what's considered to be better?
one project to hold 2 targets (iOS/MacOS) ? or 2 projects with 1 target each?

Comment: Combine them into a workspace. — What if you do have to make new targets? Dragging the actual _files_ (code, resources, etc.) from one Xcode window to another is not exactly difficult or time-consuming.

Comment: It's not really an answer, but if you haven't seen it, I recommend Apple's WWDC video "Sharing code between iOS and OS X": https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/233/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Xcode Workspace (`.xcworkspace`) under File -> New and then simply drag in both your Xcode projects under the same workspace.